# localising a text gtkmm Linux

Tags: linux, gtk

How can a string be localized to local language.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is quite a bit general... Did you even try to google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about gtkmm & i18n [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/2.21/chapter-internationalization.html.en)

Comment: Link is now 
http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.2/chapter-internationalization.html.en